# strategy counter for labels with signal long and short

Tags: pine-script

could you please help me create a counter that will create a label on the chart every other time
for example, if there is a LONG label then the next label will only be SHORT

i tried it like this

```
var x = 0
if highbar
    x += 1
if lowbar
    x != 0
```

well so i still get a lot of LONG tags then SHORT tags

Answer (score 0):

You can use a solution like in the answer to this question: [Need to establish if the last signal was toBuy or toSell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67472125/need-to-establish-if-the-last-signal-was-tobuy-or-tosell)

This explains another way to go about it: https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-allow-transitions-from-condition-ab-or-ba-but-not-aa-nor-bb

> **Disclosure**: the link in this answer points to a PineCoders FAQ entry.
> I am a member of the PineCoders community and I most probably wrote that FAQ entry. PineCoders is a TradingView-supported group of volunteer Pine coders and PineCoders' website is strictly educational. Neither TradingView nor PineCoders benefits financially from sending traffic to pinecoders.com, and the site contains no affiliate/referral links.

Comment: Thank you. This is the second time you've been helping me. If I can thank you somehow, tell me how to do it?

Comment: Always happy to help when we can. Nothing owed )