# Need to establish if the last signal was toBuy or toSell

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to create a toBuy and toSell signal based on the slope of a slowMA indicator.the problem with my code is that I get Sell signals, even without prior Buy signals. Is there a way to check if the previous signal was a buy, before the Sell signal is given, so they come in matching pairs? I thought of using valuewhen() function, but can't figure out how to apply it.
Please help

```
//@version=4
study(title="Bridger MMI ", shorttitle="MMI", overlay=true)

r = rsi(close, 21)                                                 // RSI of Close
slowMA = sma(r, 2)                                          // Moving Average of RSI 7 bars back *** this is the green one I'm watching
                                                         

angleSlowMA= (atan(slowMA[0]-slowMA[1]))*180/3.14159   // atan gives angle in radians given opposite side/adjacent, adjacent =1, therefore atan(opposite) will give angle
                                                       // to convert radians to degrees, multiply by 180 and divide by pi

toBuy = angleSlowMA >= 15 and angleSlowMA <= 30
lastWasToBuy = valuewhen(toBuy, angleSlowMA, 1)      // this gives the value of the angle at the last toBuy

toSell = angleSlowMA <15 

plotshape(toBuy, title="Slope Positive", location=location.belowbar, color=color.lime, transp=0, style=shape.triangleup, text="BUY")            
plotshape(toSell, title="Slope Negative", location=location.abovebar, color=color.yellow, transp=0, style=shape.triangledown, text="SELL")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use `var` in here to save states across bars, and only plot buy/sell markers on transitions:

```
//@version=4
study(title="Bridger MMI ", shorttitle="MMI", overlay=true)

r = rsi(close, 21)                                      // RSI of Close
slowMA = sma(r, 2)                                      // Moving Average of RSI 7 bars back *** this is the green one I'm watching
                                                         
angleSlowMA= (atan(slowMA[0]-slowMA[1]))*180/3.14159    // atan gives angle in radians given opposite side/adjacent, adjacent =1, therefore atan(opposite) will give angle

// Use `var` to save state of vars across bars.
var bool toBuy = false
var bool toSell = false
if angleSlowMA >= 15 and angleSlowMA <= 30
    toBuy  := true
    toSell := false
else if toBuy and angleSlowMA <15
    toSell := true
    toBuy  := false

lastWasToBuy = valuewhen(toBuy, angleSlowMA, 1)      // this gives the value of the angle at the last toBuy

// Only show markers on transitions.
plotshape(toBuy and not toBuy[1], title="Slope Positive", location=location.belowbar, color=color.lime, transp=0, style=shape.triangleup, text="BUY")            
plotshape(toSell and not toSell[1], title="Slope Negative", location=location.abovebar, color=color.yellow, transp=0, style=shape.triangledown, text="SELL")
```

[image]

[EDIT: 2021.05.10 13:24 — LucF]

Debugging plots:

```
plotchar(toBuy, "toBuy", "▲", location.top, size = size.tiny)
plotchar(toSell, "toSell", "▼", location.bottom, size = size.tiny)
```

Comment: Wow , thank you so much, that is truly elegant, boy I wish I knew what I was doing 

Comment: May I ask you one more thing, I follow the use of variables, but I don't understand the "only show markers on transitions" part. toBuy and toSell are series correct, how does negating toBuy[1] selects only transitions points?, sorry , i know this must be tedious to explain to a total newbie, but there are not many good books on how to do this. Thank you for any help!

Comment: np. Happy to help. Because the values of your `toBuy` and `toSell` variables persist across bars, they can stay `true` for many bars. Plotting your markers only when they are `false` on the previous  bar and then `true` on the current one, avoids successive plots. We have added debugging plots at the end of our answer. Try these at the end of your script to see exactly when those variables are `true/false`.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense , thank you. These debugging plots are a great idea too, I have been looking for a way to see what values the variable hold at which times, but I was looking for some kind of an "echo" like function, unfortunately, since everything goes on chart in Pine Script, I guess there is no such thing, so these are great thank you. ANy other sources of basic info for a newbie you can suggest?

Comment: There is a good [page on debugging techniques in the usrman](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/Debugging.html). This is the best place to start your Pine journey. Will point you in all the right directions: 
 https://www.tradingview.com/?solution=43000561836